# Soap request works in browser, but not in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, soap

So I have a web url (some ip address)/SpecialService.asmx?op=GetAllBonuses that I use to make a SOAP request. When I just plug it into Chrome, /SpecialService.asmx?op=GetAllBonuses&(credentials passed in), I get my data back. However, when I add the url to visual studio as a web reference and use the generated class, I don't get any results back. Any idea? I hope this makes sense, as I wasn't entirely sure how to explain it..
EDIT: Code generated by Visual Studio, under a class called SpecialService

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://phoenixservice3.loyaltylane.com/SpecialService/GetAllBonuses", RequestNamespace="http://phoenixservice3.loyaltylane.com/SpecialService", ResponseNamespace="http://phoenixservice3.loyaltylane.com/SpecialService", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    public Bonus[] GetAllBonuses(string userName, string password, System.DateTime date, string storeNumber) {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("GetAllBonuses", new object[] {
                    userName,
                    password,
                    date,
                    storeNumber});
        return ((Bonus[])(results[0]));
    }
```

And then I call it by this:

```
Bonus[] grabbed = SpecialService.GetAllBonuses(userName, password, DateTime.Today, storeNumber);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you are using? Without it we cannot tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I've added the code generated by the web reference, and the line of code I use. Will that help?

Comment: Can you also show the code of how you construct `SpecialService`? Did you add the web reference from the same URL as you're accessing in the browser?

Comment: Yes. I used the same url to make the web reference.